# Introduction Javascript functions - syntax

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

so I am currently in a Bootcamp (full-stack) through the University of Arizona. I've been coding for about 45 days total, and seem to be hitting a major wall with my very first Javascript assignment.
I'm to make a Rock, Paper, Scissors game.

```
My first step:  <script type="text/javascript">
var options = ["r", "p", "s"];

document.onkeyup = function()  {
    var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keycode).toLowerCase();

    console.log(userGuess);

    var computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random()=options.length)];

    console.log(computerGuess);
}
```

When entering console to see if random button stroke would, in fact, produce a lowercase "r", "p", or "s" this is what I encountered in Chrome's console:

> rockPapersScissors.html:15 
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: "Invalid left-hand side in assignment
>       at HTMLDocument.document.onkeyup (rockPapersScissors.html:15)"

Even with knowing the exact line and character of error, I'm still at a loss.  Maybe because I am such a newbie, but, man, It's like, just as soon as I begin to get a hold on the material - BAM - another deluge of gibberish washes over me.

Please excuse my beginner question, but the time and effort will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Math.random()=options.length` <-- because of this. This should not be an equal. It should be a `*`

Comment: A hint: if it is talking about an "assignment" then look for the assignment operator, `=`, on the line in question. There are two of them on that line, only one of which makes sense.

Comment: nnnn, yes, thank you for that astute observation. Perhaps I should go to bed with that kind of error. But then again, I'm in a bootcamp,  85% of the learning being self-taught. Your tip will be one I'll never forget - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on this line

```
var computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random()=options.length)];
```

You were assigning the `options.length` to `Math.random()`

To get a random item in an array you should use `*`

```
var computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The fix is awesome, but what I really appreciate is the reason why! Again, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @RobertZobrist Because..Why would you assign a number to `Math.random()` + You cannot assign something to it. Like the errors tells you `"Invalid left-hand side in assignment` Your left-hande side is `Math.random()`

Comment: @RobertZobrist If it fixed your problem, dont forget to tick the answer

Comment: thanks, again. This is my very first stack ? - go figure.